# VB6 Shell with parameters

Tags: command-line, vb6

I can open up the command line and type

```
 devenv m:\myproject.sln /build Release
```

This works great.

Now I wanted to invoke the command line from VB6 and execute the same command.

But that doesn't work. I am not sure if I missed something.

Here is my code:

```
dim lRet&
lRet = Shell("cmd /k devenv m:\myproject.sln /build Release", 0)
```

The command line opens up, but the command itself ("devenv m:\myproject.sln /build Release") is not executed.

Does anybody see why?

Comment: What do you see in console output when running the same code, but with vbNormalFocus (=1) instead of vbHide (=0) as a second parameter to Shell()? You can also use ProcessExplorer or similar tool to check command line arguments that have been passed to created instance of cmd.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to type CMD inside `SHELL` command. Try this:

```
dim lRet&
lRet = Shell("devenv m:\myproject.sln /build Release", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Parameter As String
Dim Res As Long
Dim Filename As String
    Filename = "C:\myfolder\myfile.exe" 'Check file is here first
If Dir(Filename) = "" Then
    MsgBox Filename & " not found with parameter " & Parameter, vbInformation
Else
    Res = Shell(Filename & " " & Parameter, vbHide)
End If
```

If you are expecting a return value use 
Res = Shell(Filename & " " & Parameter, vbHide)
otherwise 
Shell Filename & " " & Parameter, vbHide